# Dictionary value initialization on lookup

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following:

```
mylist = ['a','b','c','d']
mydict = {}
for val in mylist:
    if val not in mydict:
        mydict[val] = []
    mydict[val].append(1)
```

Is there any way to avoid the double lookup ("`val in mydict`" and "`mydict[val]`")?

Note - I've tried using a default return value (i.e. `mydict.get(val, []).append(1)`), but the new list isn't actually registered in the dictionary as the value for the key. For example:

```
mydict = {}
mydict.get('not_in_dict','default')
mydict
```

returns `{}`. In my case I want something that would return `{'not_in_dict' : 'default'}`.

Or is the correct answer here that I should't worry about double lookups? (e.g. "chill, dude, don't optimize if you don't have to" or "python is awesome, it takes care of this already").

I'm using python 3.4.

Comment: @Ashwini - thank you for pointing out the duplicate question. The answer there was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dict.setdefault](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm)

```
mylist = ['a','b','c','d']
mydict = {}
for val in mylist:
    mydict.setdefault(val,[])
    mydict[val].append(1)
```

Or use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which is more efficient

```
from collections import defaultdict
mylist = ['a','b','c','d']
mydict = defaultdict(list)
for val in mylist:
    mydict[val].append(1)


In [14]: mylist = ['a','b','c','d']    
In [15]: mydict = {}    
In [16]: %%timeit
   ....: for val in mylist:
   ....:     mydict.setdefault(val,[])
   ....:     mydict[val].append(1)
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 µs per loop

In [18]: mydict = defaultdict(list)
In [19]: %%timeit
   ....: for val in mylist:
   ....:     mydict[val].append(1)
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 603 ns per loop
```

Comment: It appears that your example is still doing two lookups: mydict.setdefault(val,[]) and then again with mydict[val].append(1). Does the time change when you chain the two commands: mydict.setdefault(val,[]).append(1)?

Comment: the most efficient solution would be `defaultdict`, your original code is not far behind, checking if a key exists is constant time so it is  pretty cheap to check if the keys exists so your own code is pretty efficient.

Comment: I guess then the answer really is that it doesn't matter all that much. I'm sure there is a python quote somewhere out there about premature optimization being the root of all evil. :)

Comment: There sure is, defaultdict is a handy tool though so worth learning about. As far as optimization goes I always get my code completed and working correctly then worry about optimisation if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(list)
mydict['not in dict'] = 'foo'
```